# Closing the Window after Some Time in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

Using Selenium I am opening a window. I want to close and Quit the Window after the Button is Clicked. How can I achieve that in Selenium. The function which I want to perform before Closing The window is Below

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='css-vote-button pds-vote-button' and starts-with(@id, 'pd-vote-button10359300')]/span[text()='Vote']"))).click();
```

Comment: `driver.quit();`

Comment: This will quit but I need to close after that function finishes

Comment: `driver.close();` will close the current tab.

Comment: Then just use driver.close() what @KunLun has mentioned.This should work.

Answer (score 1):

With `driver.close()` you can close the tab/window which WebDriver controlling.

I use this code to close all tabs/windows.

```
var tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());

while(tabs.size() > 0){

    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0)); //NoSuchWindowException

    driver.close();

    tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());

}
```

Comment: Can we wait around 10 Seconds before Closing the Window. How can we do that ?

Comment: @Ruban4Axis You can use `Thead.sleep(10000) //ms`, but this can produce `InterruptedException` if you `interrupt();` the thread which called `sleep`. For more details read here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_sleep_millis.htm and https://www.javatpoint.com/interrupting-a-thread